# Braintree Java Implementation of Validation Error codes creating customer

Tags: java, braintree, braintree-data

I am using braintree with java,
While creating the customer profile, I am getting the error messages like this

```
try{

            CustomerRequest request = new CustomerRequest()
                    .firstName("Kim")
                    .lastName("Jones")
                    .company("Jones Co.")
                    .email("mark.jones@example.com")
                    .fax("419-555-1234")
                    .phone("614-555-1234")
                    .id("asdasda23423433")
                    .paymentMethodNonce("88878692-0157-40c3-b23b-51c113ebf160")

                    .website("http://example.com");
                Result<Customer> result = gateway.customer().create(request);
                System.out.println("\n\n\t isSuccess=="+result.getSubscription());

        ValidationErrors validationErrors=result.getErrors();


for (ValidationError validationError : validationErrors.getAllDeepValidationErrors()) {
            ValidationErrorCode validationErrorCode=validationError.getCode();
            System.out.println("\n\t code==>"+validationErrorCode+"\t msg- "+validationError.getMessage());
        }
```

The problem is this validationErrorCode is coming as constant For ex:

> CUSTOMER_ID_IS_IN_USE
>
> PAYMENT_METHOD_PAYMENT_METHOD_NONCE_UNKNOWN

I didn't find this error codes in document anywhere

How I can get the remaining error codes?

I have been stuck.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is the list of [Braintree Validation Errors](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/validation-errors/all/java).

Comment: yes but I got above constants (i.e CUSTOMER_ID_IS_IN_USE) as errors not its integer codes. I want to know whether there is any doc for such types of constants

Comment: The constants are available in [the library source](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/braintreegateway/ValidationErrorCode.java).